# Creating a for loop to plot multiple data series in ggplot

Tags: r, loops

I'm pretty sure this should be really straightforward but I cannot find a solution and cannot see the answer in other questions on for loops in r. I have a dataset datDET that contains 21 data sets of different 'Gels', and I want to make a plot where I have a series from each dataset plotted altogether. I have the following code, however, I just get the error that there is an unexpected symbol in my code, which is the ] after the i. Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated! Here is my current code!

```
G1.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==1,]
G2.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==2,]
G3.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==3,]
G4.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==4,]
G5.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==5,]
G6.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==6,]
G7.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==7,]
G8.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==8,]
G9.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==9,]
G10.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==10,]
G11.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==11,]
G12.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==12,]
G13.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==13,]
G14.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==14,]
G15.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==15,]
G16.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==16,]
G17.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==17,]
G18.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==18,]
G19.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==19,]
G20.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==20,]
G21.dat <- datDET[datDET$Gel==21,]

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(datDET, aes(x = NO3, y = Depth))

for (i in c(1:21)){
p1 <- p + geom_point(data=Gi.dat)
}
```

Comment: Does the loop have to go over each named object og Gxx.dat?  You could just write the loop portion to loop through the subsetting:  `p1 <- p + geom_point( data=datDET [datDET$Gel== i, ] )`

Comment: Better to split the data.frame into a list of data.frames using `split` like `myList <- split(datDET, datDET$Gel)`. Then you can use your `for` loop to run through the list and produce graphs like `for (i in seq_along(myList)){; print(p + geom_point(data=myList[[i]])); }` or store these plots in a list with `lapply` like `myPlotList <- lapply(myList, p + geom_point(data=myList[[i]]))`.

Answer (score 0):

`data=Gi.dat` is looking for an object named `Gi.dat` which you don't have. If you want to be able to replace the i with the looped value, you'll have to use `get` and `paste`

`data=get(paste0("G",i,".dat"))`